Arduino aRest no matching function issue
Using aRest api library, II get 78:525: error: no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::print(ApiCommandClass&) at the line
return apiReturn.indexOf(ERROR) > 0 ? INVALID : SUCCESS;

in the function:
int apiCallBand(String request) {
    String action = "band";
    ApiCommandClass command(action, request);
    String apiReturn = SWRRestFunctionsClass::ProcessCommand(command.ToJson());
    client.println(apiReturn);
    return apiReturn.indexOf(ERROR) > 0 ? INVALID : SUCCESS;
}

referenced by

// Create aREST instance
aREST rest = aREST();
// Create an instance of the server
WiFiServer server(LISTEN_PORT);
WiFiClient client;
    char BAND[] = "band";
    rest.function(BAND, apiCallBand);

I don't understand how the return of an int would get an error in the  ApiCommandClass???
Thanks
Abbott
I tried for a clean build. Ugggh

the error tells you everything you need to know. it complains about your attempt to call HardwareSerial::print with an argument of the wrong type. There is no overload for type ApiCommandClass&.
